# Integer tree sort in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I have this algorithm for sorting integer arrays. Basically, it's a balanced tree sort which creates a tree node for each **distinct** integer, and in each tree node it maintains a counter counting how many times the integer key appeared so far in the array being scanned. After the array is scanned, and the tree is complete, the algorithm simply traverses the tree in order dumping the sorted integers into the input range.

If the input range contains \$k\$ distinct integers, the running time of this sort is \$\Theta(n + k \log k)\$. Since \$k\$ cannot exceed \$n\$, the worst case running time is \$\Theta(n \log n)\$. The constant factors, however, are large.

See what I have below.

**`IntTreeSort.java:`**

```
package net.coderodde.util.sorting;

/**
 * This class implements a funky tree sort algorithm for sorting integers.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Feb 21, 2016)
 */
public class IntTreeSort {

    public static void sort(int[] array) {
        sort(array, 0, array.length);
    }

    public static void sort(int[] array, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        if (toIndex - fromIndex < 2) {
            return;
        }

        new IntTreeSort(array, fromIndex, toIndex).sort();
    }

    private final int[] array;
    private final int fromIndex;
    private final int toIndex;
    private final HashTableEntry[] table;
    private final int mask;
    private TreeNode root;

    private IntTreeSort(int[] array, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        this.array     = array;
        this.fromIndex = fromIndex;
        this.toIndex   = toIndex;

        int capacity   = computeCapacity(toIndex - fromIndex);

        this.table     = new HashTableEntry[capacity];
        this.mask      = capacity - 1;
    }

    private static int computeCapacity(int length) {
        int ret = 1;

        while (ret < length) {
            ret <<= 1;
        }

        return ret;
    }

    private static final class TreeNode {
        int key;
        int count;
        int height;
        TreeNode left;
        TreeNode right;
        TreeNode parent;

        TreeNode(int key) {
            this.key = key;
            this.count = 1;
        }
    }

    private static final class HashTableEntry {
        int key;
        TreeNode treeNode;
        HashTableEntry nextEntry;

        HashTableEntry(int key, TreeNode treeNode, HashTableEntry nextEntry) {
            this.key = key;
            this.treeNode = treeNode;
            this.nextEntry = nextEntry;
        }
    }

    private static int height(TreeNode node) {
        return node == null ? -1 : node.height;
    }

    private int index(int element) {
        return element & mask;
    }

    private TreeNode findTreeNode(int element, int elementHash) {
        HashTableEntry entry = table[elementHash];

        while (entry != null && entry.treeNode.key != element) {
            entry = entry.nextEntry;
        }

        return entry == null ? null : entry.treeNode;
    }

    private void sort() {
        int initialKey = array[fromIndex];
        root = new TreeNode(initialKey);
        table[index(initialKey)] = new HashTableEntry(initialKey,
                                                      root, 
                                                      null);

        for (int i = fromIndex + 1; i < toIndex; ++i) {
            int currentElement = array[i];
            int currentElementHash = index(currentElement);

            TreeNode treeNode = findTreeNode(currentElement, 
                                             currentElementHash);

            if (treeNode != null) {
                treeNode.count++;
            } else {
                TreeNode newnode = add(currentElement);
                HashTableEntry newentry =
                        new HashTableEntry(currentElement,
                                           newnode,
                                           table[currentElementHash]);
                table[currentElementHash] = newentry;
            }
        }

        TreeNode node = minimum(root);
        int index = fromIndex;

        while (node != null) {
            int key = node.key;
            int count = node.count;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
                array[index++] = key;
            }

            node = successor(node);
        }
    }

    private TreeNode minimum(TreeNode node) {
        while (node.left != null) {
            node = node.left;
        }

        return node;
    }

    private TreeNode successor(TreeNode node) {
        if (node.right != null) {
            return minimum(node.right);
        }

        TreeNode parent = node.parent;

        while (parent != null && parent.right == node) {
            node = parent;
            parent = parent.parent;
        }

        return parent;
    }

    private TreeNode add(int key) {
        TreeNode parent = null;
        TreeNode node = root;

        while (node != null) {
            if (key < node.key) {
                parent = node;
                node = node.left;
            } else if (key > node.key) {
                parent = node;
                node = node.right;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        TreeNode newnode = new TreeNode(key);

        if (key < parent.key) {
            parent.left = newnode;
        } else {
            parent.right = newnode;
        }

        newnode.parent = parent;
        fixAfterInsertion(parent);
        return newnode;
    }

    private void fixAfterInsertion(TreeNode node) {
        TreeNode parent = node.parent;
        TreeNode grandParent;
        TreeNode subTree;

        while (parent != null) {
            if (height(parent.left) == height(parent.right) + 2) {
                grandParent = parent.parent;

                if (height(parent.left.left) >= height(parent.left.right)) {
                    subTree = rightRotate(parent);
                } else {
                    subTree = leftRightRotate(parent);
                }

                if (grandParent == null) {
                    root = subTree;
                } else if (grandParent.left == parent) {
                    grandParent.left = subTree;
                } else {
                    grandParent.right = subTree;
                }

                if (grandParent != null) {
                    grandParent.height = Math.max(
                            height(grandParent.left),
                            height(grandParent.right)) + 1;
                }

                return;
            } else if (height(parent.right) == height(parent.left) + 2) {
                grandParent = parent.parent;

                if (height(parent.right.right) >= height(parent.right.left)) {
                    subTree = leftRotate(parent);
                } else {
                    subTree = rightLeftRotate(parent);
                }

                if (grandParent == null) {
                    root = subTree;
                } else if (grandParent.left == parent) {
                    grandParent.left = subTree;
                } else {
                    grandParent.right = subTree;
                }

                if (grandParent != null) {
                    grandParent.height =
                            Math.max(height(grandParent.left),
                                     height(grandParent.right)) + 1;
                }

                return;
            }

            parent.height = Math.max(height(parent.left), 
                                     height(parent.right)) + 1;
            parent = parent.parent;
        }
    }

    private TreeNode leftRotate(TreeNode node1) {
        TreeNode node2 = node1.right;
        node2.parent = node1.parent;
        node1.parent = node2;
        node1.right = node2.left;
        node2.left = node1;

        if (node1.right != null) {
            node1.right.parent = node1;
        }

        node1.height = Math.max(height(node1.left), height(node1.right)) + 1;
        node2.height = Math.max(height(node2.left), height(node2.right)) + 1;
        return node2;
    }

    private TreeNode rightRotate(TreeNode node1) {
        TreeNode node2 = node1.left;
        node2.parent = node1.parent;
        node1.parent = node2;
        node1.left = node2.right;
        node2.right = node1;

        if (node1.left != null) {
            node1.left.parent = node1;
        }

        node1.height = Math.max(height(node1.left), height(node1.right)) + 1;
        node2.height = Math.max(height(node2.left), height(node2.right)) + 1;
        return node2;
    }

    private TreeNode rightLeftRotate(TreeNode node1) {
        TreeNode node2 = node1.right;
        node1.right = rightRotate(node2);
        return leftRotate(node1);
    }

    private TreeNode leftRightRotate(TreeNode node1) {
        TreeNode node2 = node1.left;
        node1.left = leftRotate(node2);
        return rightRotate(node1);
    }
}
```

**`Demo.java:`**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import net.coderodde.util.sorting.IntTreeSort;

public class Demo {

    private static final int CONSOLE_WIDTH = 80;
    private static final int DISTINCT_INTS = 500;
    private static final int LENGTH = 10_000_000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(title("Small number of distinct integers"));
        int[] array = new int[LENGTH];
        long seed = System.nanoTime();
        Random random = new Random(seed);

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
            array[i] = 3 * random.nextInt(DISTINCT_INTS);
        }

        System.out.println("Seed = " + seed);

        profile(array);
    }

    private static void profile(int[] array) {
        int[] array2 = array.clone();

        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        Arrays.sort(array);
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.printf("Arrays.sort in %.2f milliseconds.\n",
                          (endTime - startTime) / 1E6);

        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        IntTreeSort.sort(array2);
        endTime = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.printf("IntTreeSort.sort in %.2f milliseconds.\n",
                          (endTime - startTime) / 1E6);

        System.out.println("Equals: " + Arrays.equals(array, array2));
    }

    public static String title(String text) {
        return title(text, '=');
    }

    private static String title(String text, char c) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        int left = (CONSOLE_WIDTH - 2 - text.length()) / 2;
        int right = CONSOLE_WIDTH - 2 - text.length() - left;

        for (int i = 0; i < left; ++i) {
            sb.append(c);
        }

        sb.append(' ').append(text).append(' ');

        for (int i = 0; i < right; ++i) {
            sb.append(c);
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**Performance figures**

On arrays with really small \$k\$ I get the following digits:

```
Seed = 293795935189551
Arrays.sort in 646.30 milliseconds.
IntTreeSort.sort in 149.52 milliseconds.
Equals: true
```

**Critique request**

Please tell me whatever comes to mind.

Comment: I still don't get it: You use hashing to find the "clique" of each item: add to a (n Array)List. At end of input put all lists into an array, sort, output.

Comment: @greybeard I don't quite comprehend your text. Could you use simpler words and sentences?