Comparing two Tree sort algorithm variations implemented in Java
I have this repository. It contains three variations of a simple sorting algorithm for integer keys.
The idea is that we keep a balanced BST in which each node holds the integer key and its frequency. Also, we keep around a hash table mapping integer keys to their respective BST nodes. When the algorithm considers the next key, it first checks to see whether the hash table maps it to a tree node \$n\$. If yes, it just increments the frequency  of \$n\$. Otherwise, two new entries are created and one of them is inserted into the BST, and one into the hash table. Finally, when the entire input range is processed, it performs in-order traversal of the underlying BST and dumps all the data to the input array.
The running time of this sort is \$\Theta(N + \Delta \log \Delta)\$, where \$\Delta\$ is the number of distinct integers in the input range. Uses \$\Theta(N)\$ space.
Also, the hash table collision chains are actually balanced BSTs. That way, the algorithm does not slow down to quadratic running time on the degenerate case where all the keys are distinct but hash to the same hash table bucket.
Finally, all the balanced BSTs are implemented as AVL-trees.
Code
com.github.coderodde.util.IntTreeSortV2.java:
package com.github.coderodde.util;

/**
 * This class implements the variation of integer tree sort where instead of 
 * collision chains we use collision trees.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.0.0 (Aug 30, 2024)
 * @since 1.0.0 (Aug 30, 2024)
 */
public class IntTreeSortV2 {

    public static void sort(int[] array) {
        sort(array, 0, array.length);
    }

    public static void sort(int[] array, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        if (toIndex - fromIndex < 2) {
            return;
        }

        new IntTreeSortV2(array, fromIndex, toIndex).sort();
    }

    private final int[] array;
    private final int fromIndex;
    private final int toIndex;
    private final HashTableTreeNode[] table;
    private final int mask;
    private TreeNode root;

    private IntTreeSortV2(int[] array, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        this.array     = array;
        this.fromIndex = fromIndex;
        this.toIndex   = toIndex;
        int capacity   = computeCapacity(toIndex - fromIndex);
        this.table     = new HashTableTreeNode[capacity];
        this.mask      = capacity - 1;
    }

    private static int computeCapacity(int length) {
        int ret = 1;

        while (ret < length) {
            ret *= 2;
        }

        return ret;
    }

    private static final class TreeNode {
        int key;
        int count;
        int height;
        TreeNode left;
        TreeNode right;
        TreeNode parent;

        TreeNode(int key) {
            this.key = key;
            this.count = 1;
        }
    }

    private static final class HashTableTreeNode {
        int key;
        int height;
        TreeNode treeNode;
        HashTableTreeNode left;
        HashTableTreeNode right;
        HashTableTreeNode parent;

        HashTableTreeNode(int key, TreeNode treeNode) {
            this.key = key;
            this.treeNode = treeNode;
        }
    }

    private static int height(TreeNode node) {
        return node == null ? -1 : node.height;
    }
    
    private static int height(HashTableTreeNode node) {
        return node == null ? -1 : node.height;
    }

    private int hashTableIndex(int element) {
        return element & mask;
    }

    private TreeNode findTreeNode(int element, int elementHash) {
        HashTableTreeNode node = table[elementHash];
        
        while (node != null) {
            if (node.key == element) {
                return node.treeNode;
            }
            
            if (element < node.key) {
                node = node.left;
            } else {
                node = node.right;
            }
        }
        
        return null;
    }

    private void sort() {
        int initialKey = array[fromIndex];
        root = new TreeNode(initialKey);
        table[hashTableIndex(initialKey)] = new HashTableTreeNode(initialKey, 
                                                                  root);

        for (int i = fromIndex + 1; i < toIndex; ++i) {
            int currentElement = array[i];
            int currentElementHash = hashTableIndex(currentElement);

            TreeNode treeNode = findTreeNode(currentElement, 
                                             currentElementHash);

            if (treeNode != null) {
                treeNode.count++;
            } else {
                TreeNode newnode = addTreeNode(currentElement);
                
                HashTableTreeNode newEntry =
                        new HashTableTreeNode(
                                currentElement, 
                                newnode);
                
                addHashTable(newEntry);
            }
        }

        TreeNode node = minimum(root);
        int index = fromIndex;

        while (node != null) {
            int key = node.key;
            int count = node.count;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
                array[index++] = key;
            }

            node = successor(node);
        }
    }

    private TreeNode minimum(TreeNode node) {
        while (node.left != null) {
            node = node.left;
        }

        return node;
    }

    private TreeNode successor(TreeNode node) {
        if (node.right != null) {
            return minimum(node.right);
        }

        TreeNode parent = node.parent;

        while (parent != null && parent.right == node) {
            node = parent;
            parent = parent.parent;
        }

        return parent;
    }

        private TreeNode addTreeNode(int key) {
        TreeNode parent = null;
        TreeNode node = root;

        while (node != null) {
            if (key < node.key) {
                parent = node;
                node = node.left;
            } else if (key > node.key) {
                parent = node;
                node = node.right;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        TreeNode newnode = new TreeNode(key);

        if (key < parent.key) {
            parent.left = newnode;
        } else {
            parent.right = newnode;
        }

        newnode.parent = parent;
        fixAfterInsertion(newnode);
        return newnode;
    }
    
    private void addHashTable(HashTableTreeNode newNode) {
        int key = newNode.key;
        int hash = hashTableIndex(key);
        HashTableTreeNode parent = null;
        HashTableTreeNode node = table[hash];
        
        if (node == null) {
            table[hash] = newNode;
            return;
        }
        
        while (node != null) {
            if (key < node.key) {
                parent = node;
                node = node.left;
            } else if (node.key < key) {
                parent = node;
                node = node.right;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        
        if (key < parent.key) {
            parent.left = newNode;
        } else {
            parent.right = newNode;
        }
        
        newNode.parent = parent;
        fixAfterInsertion(newNode.parent);
    }
    
    private void fixAfterInsertion(TreeNode node) {
        TreeNode parent = node.parent;
        TreeNode grandParent;
        TreeNode subTree;

        while (parent != null) {
            if (height(parent.left) == height(parent.right) + 2) {
                grandParent = parent.parent;

                if (height(parent.left.left) >= height(parent.left.right)) {
                    subTree = rightRotate(parent);
                } else {
                    subTree = leftRightRotate(parent);
                }

                if (grandParent == null) {
                    root = subTree;
                } else if (grandParent.left == parent) {
                    grandParent.left = subTree;
                } else {
                    grandParent.right = subTree;
                }

                if (grandParent != null) {
                    grandParent.height = Math.max(
                            height(grandParent.left),
                            height(grandParent.right)) + 1;
                }

                return;
            } else if (height(parent.right) == height(parent.left) + 2) {
                grandParent = parent.parent;

                if (height(parent.right.right) >= height(parent.right.left)) {
                    subTree = leftRotate(parent);
                } else {
                    subTree = rightLeftRotate(parent);
                }

                if (grandParent == null) {
                    root = subTree;
                } else if (grandParent.left == parent) {
                    grandParent.left = subTree;
                } else {
                    grandParent.right = subTree;
                }

                if (grandParent != null) {
                    grandParent.height =
                            Math.max(height(grandParent.left),
                                     height(grandParent.right)) + 1;
                }

                return;
            }

            parent.height = Math.max(height(parent.left), 
                                     height(parent.right)) + 1;
            parent = parent.parent;
        }
        
        
    }
    
    private void fixAfterInsertion(HashTableTreeNode node) {
        HashTableTreeNode parent = node.parent;
        HashTableTreeNode grandParent;
        HashTableTreeNode subTree;

        while (parent != null) {
            if (height(parent.left) == height(parent.right) + 2) {
                grandParent = parent.parent;

                if (height(parent.left.left) >= height(parent.left.right)) {
                    subTree = rightRotate(parent);
                } else {
                    subTree = leftRightRotate(parent);
                }

                if (grandParent == null) {
                    table[hashTableIndex(node.key)] = subTree;
                } else if (grandParent.left == parent) {
                    grandParent.left = subTree;
                } else {
                    grandParent.right = subTree;
                }

                if (grandParent != null) {
                    grandParent.height = Math.max(
                            height(grandParent.left),
                            height(grandParent.right)) + 1;
                }

                return;
            } else if (height(parent.right) == height(parent.left) + 2) {
                grandParent = parent.parent;

                if (height(parent.right.right) >= height(parent.right.left)) {
                    subTree = leftRotate(parent);
                } else {
                    subTree = rightLeftRotate(parent);
                }

                if (grandParent == null) {
                    table[hashTableIndex(node.key)] = subTree;
                } else if (grandParent.left == parent) {
                    grandParent.left = subTree;
                } else {
                    grandParent.right = subTree;
                }

                if (grandParent != null) {
                    grandParent.height =
                            Math.max(height(grandParent.left),
                                     height(grandParent.right)) + 1;
                }

                return;
            }

            parent.height = Math.max(height(parent.left), 
                                     height(parent.right)) + 1;
            parent = parent.parent;
        }
    }

    private TreeNode leftRotate(TreeNode node1) {
        TreeNode node2 = node1.right;
        node2.parent = node1.parent;
        node1.parent = node2;
        node1.right = node2.left;
        node2.left = node1;

        if (node1.right != null) {
            node1.right.parent = node1;
        }

        node1.height = Math.max(height(node1.left), height(node1.right)) + 1;
        node2.height = Math.max(height(node2.left), height(node2.right)) + 1;
        return node2;
    }

    private TreeNode rightRotate(TreeNode node1) {
        TreeNode node2 = node1.left;
        node2.parent = node1.parent;
        node1.parent = node2;
        node1.left = node2.right;
        node2.right = node1;

        if (node1.left != null) {
            node1.left.parent = node1;
        }

        node1.height = Math.max(height(node1.left), height(node1.right)) + 1;
        node2.height = Math.max(height(node2.left), height(node2.right)) + 1;
        return node2;
    }

    private TreeNode rightLeftRotate(TreeNode node1) {
        TreeNode node2 = node1.right;
        node1.right = rightRotate(node2);
        return leftRotate(node1);
    }

    private TreeNode leftRightRotate(TreeNode node1) {
        TreeNode node2 = node1.left;
        node1.left = leftRotate(node2);
        return rightRotate(node1);
    }

    private HashTableTreeNode leftRotate(HashTableTreeNode node1) {
        HashTableTreeNode node2 = node1.right;
        node2.parent = node1.parent;
        node1.parent = node2;
        node1.right = node2.left;
        node2.left = node1;

        if (node1.right != null) {
            node1.right.parent = node1;
        }

        node1.height = Math.max(height(node1.left), height(node1.right)) + 1;
        node2.height = Math.max(height(node2.left), height(node2.right)) + 1;
        return node2;
    }

    private HashTableTreeNode rightRotate(HashTableTreeNode node1) {
        HashTableTreeNode node2 = node1.left;
        node2.parent = node1.parent;
        node1.parent = node2;
        node1.left = node2.right;
        node2.right = node1;

        if (node1.left != null) {
            node1.left.parent = node1;
        }

        node1.height = Math.max(height(node1.left), height(node1.right)) + 1;
        node2.height = Math.max(height(node2.left), height(node2.right)) + 1;
        return node2;
    }

    private HashTableTreeNode rightLeftRotate(HashTableTreeNode node1) {
        HashTableTreeNode node2 = node1.right;
        node1.right = rightRotate(node2);
        return leftRotate(node1);
    }

    private HashTableTreeNode leftRightRotate(HashTableTreeNode node1) {
        HashTableTreeNode node2 = node1.left;
        node1.left = leftRotate(node2);
        return rightRotate(node1);
    }
}

com.github.coderodde.util.IntTreeSortV3.java:
package com.github.coderodde.util;

/**
 * This class implements the variation of integer tree sort where instead of 
 * collision chains we use collision trees. Also, it adds the 
 * <i>hook optimization</i>.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.0.0 (Aug 30, 2024)
 * @since 1.0.0 (Aug 30, 2024)
 */
public class IntTreeSortV3 {

    public static void sort(int[] array) {
        sort(array, 0, array.length);
    }

    public static void sort(int[] array, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        if (toIndex - fromIndex < 2) {
            return;
        }

        new IntTreeSortV3(array, fromIndex, toIndex).sort();
    }

    private final int[] array;
    private final int fromIndex;
    private final int toIndex;
    private final HashTableTreeNode[] table;
    private final int mask;
    private TreeNode root;
    private HashTableTreeNode previousParent;

    private IntTreeSortV3(int[] array, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        this.array     = array;
        this.fromIndex = fromIndex;
        this.toIndex   = toIndex;
        int capacity   = computeCapacity(toIndex - fromIndex);
        this.table     = new HashTableTreeNode[capacity];
        this.mask      = capacity - 1;
    }

    private static int computeCapacity(int length) {
        int ret = 1;

        while (ret < length) {
            ret *= 2;
        }

        return ret;
    }

    private static final class TreeNode {
        int key;
        int count;
        int height;
        TreeNode left;
        TreeNode right;
        TreeNode parent;

        TreeNode(int key) {
            this.key = key;
            this.count = 1;
        }
    }

    private static final class HashTableTreeNode {
        int key;
        int height;
        TreeNode treeNode;
        HashTableTreeNode left;
        HashTableTreeNode right;
        HashTableTreeNode parent;

        HashTableTreeNode(int key, TreeNode treeNode) {
            this.key = key;
            this.treeNode = treeNode;
        }
    }

    private static int height(TreeNode node) {
        return node == null ? -1 : node.height;
    }
    
    private static int height(HashTableTreeNode node) {
        return node == null ? -1 : node.height;
    }

    private int hashTableIndex(int element) {
        return element & mask;
    }

    private TreeNode findTreeNode(int element, int elementHash) {
        HashTableTreeNode node = table[elementHash];
        
        while (node != null) {
            if (node.key == element) {
                return node.treeNode;
            }
            
            previousParent = node;
            
            if (element < node.key) {
                node = node.left;
            } else {
                node = node.right;
            }
        }
        
        return null;
    }

    private void sort() {
        int initialKey = array[fromIndex];
        root = new TreeNode(initialKey);
        table[hashTableIndex(initialKey)] = new HashTableTreeNode(initialKey, 
                                                                  root);
        for (int i = fromIndex + 1; i < toIndex; ++i) {
            int currentElement = array[i];
            int currentElementHash = hashTableIndex(currentElement);

            TreeNode treeNode = findTreeNode(currentElement, 
                                             currentElementHash);

            if (treeNode != null) {
                treeNode.count++;
            } else {
                TreeNode newnode = addTreeNode(currentElement);
                
                HashTableTreeNode newEntry =
                        new HashTableTreeNode(
                                currentElement, 
                                newnode);
                
                if (previousParent != null) {
                    // Hook optimization:
                    if (currentElement < previousParent.key) {
                        previousParent.left = newEntry;
                    } else {
                        previousParent.right = newEntry;
                    }

                    fixAfterInsertion(previousParent);
                    previousParent = null;
                } else {
                    addHashTable(newEntry);
                }
            }
        }

        TreeNode node = minimum(root);
        int index = fromIndex;

        while (node != null) {
            int key = node.key;
            int count = node.count;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
                array[index++] = key;
            }

            node = successor(node);
        }
    }

    private TreeNode minimum(TreeNode node) {
        while (node.left != null) {
            node = node.left;
        }

        return node;
    }

    private TreeNode successor(TreeNode node) {
        if (node.right != null) {
            return minimum(node.right);
        }

        TreeNode parent = node.parent;

        while (parent != null && parent.right == node) {
            node = parent;
            parent = parent.parent;
        }

        return parent;
    }

        private TreeNode addTreeNode(int key) {
        TreeNode parent = null;
        TreeNode node = root;

        while (node != null) {
            if (key < node.key) {
                parent = node;
                node = node.left;
            } else if (key > node.key) {
                parent = node;
                node = node.right;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        TreeNode newnode = new TreeNode(key);

        if (key < parent.key) {
            parent.left = newnode;
        } else {
            parent.right = newnode;
        }

        newnode.parent = parent;
        fixAfterInsertion(newnode);
        return newnode;
    }
    
    private void addHashTable(HashTableTreeNode newNode) {
        int key = newNode.key;
        int hash = hashTableIndex(key);
        HashTableTreeNode parent = null;
        HashTableTreeNode node = table[hash];
        
        if (node == null) {
            table[hash] = newNode;
            return;
        }
        
        while (node != null) {
            if (key < node.key) {
                parent = node;
                node = node.left;
            } else if (node.key < key) {
                parent = node;
                node = node.right;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        
        if (key < parent.key) {
            parent.left = newNode;
        } else {
            parent.right = newNode;
        }
        
        newNode.parent = parent;
        fixAfterInsertion(newNode.parent);
    }
    
    private void fixAfterInsertion(TreeNode node) {
        TreeNode parent = node.parent;
        TreeNode grandParent;
        TreeNode subTree;

        while (parent != null) {
            if (height(parent.left) == height(parent.right) + 2) {
                grandParent = parent.parent;

                if (height(parent.left.left) >= height(parent.left.right)) {
                    subTree = rightRotate(parent);
                } else {
                    subTree = leftRightRotate(parent);
                }

                if (grandParent == null) {
                    root = subTree;
                } else if (grandParent.left == parent) {
                    grandParent.left = subTree;
                } else {
                    grandParent.right = subTree;
                }

                if (grandParent != null) {
                    grandParent.height = Math.max(
                            height(grandParent.left),
                            height(grandParent.right)) + 1;
                }

                return;
            } else if (height(parent.right) == height(parent.left) + 2) {
                grandParent = parent.parent;

                if (height(parent.right.right) >= height(parent.right.left)) {
                    subTree = leftRotate(parent);
                } else {
                    subTree = rightLeftRotate(parent);
                }

                if (grandParent == null) {
                    root = subTree;
                } else if (grandParent.left == parent) {
                    grandParent.left = subTree;
                } else {
                    grandParent.right = subTree;
                }

                if (grandParent != null) {
                    grandParent.height =
                            Math.max(height(grandParent.left),
                                     height(grandParent.right)) + 1;
                }

                return;
            }

            parent.height = Math.max(height(parent.left), 
                                     height(parent.right)) + 1;
            parent = parent.parent;
        }
        
        
    }
    
    private void fixAfterInsertion(HashTableTreeNode node) {
        HashTableTreeNode parent = node.parent;
        HashTableTreeNode grandParent;
        HashTableTreeNode subTree;

        while (parent != null) {
            if (height(parent.left) == height(parent.right) + 2) {
                grandParent = parent.parent;

                if (height(parent.left.left) >= height(parent.left.right)) {
                    subTree = rightRotate(parent);
                } else {
                    subTree = leftRightRotate(parent);
                }

                if (grandParent == null) {
                    table[hashTableIndex(node.key)] = subTree;
                } else if (grandParent.left == parent) {
                    grandParent.left = subTree;
                } else {
                    grandParent.right = subTree;
                }

                if (grandParent != null) {
                    grandParent.height = Math.max(
                            height(grandParent.left),
                            height(grandParent.right)) + 1;
                }

                return;
            } else if (height(parent.right) == height(parent.left) + 2) {
                grandParent = parent.parent;

                if (height(parent.right.right) >= height(parent.right.left)) {
                    subTree = leftRotate(parent);
                } else {
                    subTree = rightLeftRotate(parent);
                }

                if (grandParent == null) {
                    table[hashTableIndex(node.key)] = subTree;
                } else if (grandParent.left == parent) {
                    grandParent.left = subTree;
                } else {
                    grandParent.right = subTree;
                }

                if (grandParent != null) {
                    grandParent.height =
                            Math.max(height(grandParent.left),
                                     height(grandParent.right)) + 1;
                }

                return;
            }

            parent.height = Math.max(height(parent.left), 
                                     height(parent.right)) + 1;
            parent = parent.parent;
        }
    }

    private TreeNode leftRotate(TreeNode node1) {
        TreeNode node2 = node1.right;
        node2.parent = node1.parent;
        node1.parent = node2;
        node1.right = node2.left;
        node2.left = node1;

        if (node1.right != null) {
            node1.right.parent = node1;
        }

        node1.height = Math.max(height(node1.left), height(node1.right)) + 1;
        node2.height = Math.max(height(node2.left), height(node2.right)) + 1;
        return node2;
    }

    private TreeNode rightRotate(TreeNode node1) {
        TreeNode node2 = node1.left;
        node2.parent = node1.parent;
        node1.parent = node2;
        node1.left = node2.right;
        node2.right = node1;

        if (node1.left != null) {
            node1.left.parent = node1;
        }

        node1.height = Math.max(height(node1.left), height(node1.right)) + 1;
        node2.height = Math.max(height(node2.left), height(node2.right)) + 1;
        return node2;
    }

    private TreeNode rightLeftRotate(TreeNode node1) {
        TreeNode node2 = node1.right;
        node1.right = rightRotate(node2);
        return leftRotate(node1);
    }

    private TreeNode leftRightRotate(TreeNode node1) {
        TreeNode node2 = node1.left;
        node1.left = leftRotate(node2);
        return rightRotate(node1);
    }

    private HashTableTreeNode leftRotate(HashTableTreeNode node1) {
        HashTableTreeNode node2 = node1.right;
        node2.parent = node1.parent;
        node1.parent = node2;
        node1.right = node2.left;
        node2.left = node1;

        if (node1.right != null) {
            node1.right.parent = node1;
        }

        node1.height = Math.max(height(node1.left), height(node1.right)) + 1;
        node2.height = Math.max(height(node2.left), height(node2.right)) + 1;
        return node2;
    }

    private HashTableTreeNode rightRotate(HashTableTreeNode node1) {
        HashTableTreeNode node2 = node1.left;
        node2.parent = node1.parent;
        node1.parent = node2;
        node1.left = node2.right;
        node2.right = node1;

        if (node1.left != null) {
            node1.left.parent = node1;
        }

        node1.height = Math.max(height(node1.left), height(node1.right)) + 1;
        node2.height = Math.max(height(node2.left), height(node2.right)) + 1;
        return node2;
    }

    private HashTableTreeNode rightLeftRotate(HashTableTreeNode node1) {
        HashTableTreeNode node2 = node1.right;
        node1.right = rightRotate(node2);
        return leftRotate(node1);
    }

    private HashTableTreeNode leftRightRotate(HashTableTreeNode node1) {
        HashTableTreeNode node2 = node1.left;
        node1.left = leftRotate(node2);
        return rightRotate(node1);
    }
}

Typical benchmark output
seed = 1724998148175
Warming up...

Warmed up in 80 milliseconds.
Benchmarking on random data:
V1:  1204 milliseconds.
V2:  1180 milliseconds.
V3:  1196 milliseconds.
JDK: 116 milliseconds.
Algorithms agree: true.
V1  sorted: true.
V2  sorted: true.
V3  sorted: true.
JDK sorted: true.

Benchmarking on degenerate data:
V1:  1419 milliseconds.
V2:  21 milliseconds.
V3:  16 milliseconds.
JDK: 3 milliseconds.
Algorithms agree: true.
V1  sorted: true.
V2  sorted: true.
V3  sorted: true.
JDK sorted: true.

Benchmarking on sparse data:
V1:  764 milliseconds.
V2:  727 milliseconds.
V3:  737 milliseconds.
JDK: 1881 milliseconds.
Algorithms agree: true.
V1  sorted: true.
V2  sorted: true.
V2  sorted: true.
JDK sorted: true.

As one can see, both of the algorithms perform better than Arrays.sort on random sparse data.
Critique request
As always, please tell me anything that comes to mind.

Your results show V1 benchmarks, but there's no corresponding code.  Is that an oversight?  Did you really mean to include only V2 and V3?

@TobySpeight It’s here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/120689/integer-tree-sort-in-java

The code is a bit hard to follow because the TreeNode is not encapsulated properly: the classes are very long and there are random tree operation methods scattered here and there. The methods that operate on a tree node should be defined in the TreeNode class and then TreeNode should be extracted into a standalone (package private?) class shared by both V2 and V3.

@TorbenPutkonen Point. Unfortunately I am short on time and energy to fix it. :(
